# Django won't create a table for one model of many in an app

Tags: python, django

*I'm using Django 1.9*

For whatever reason, I simply cannot get Django to create a table for any more models in my `products` app. After I added the `store` model and registered it on `admin.py` and running `manage.py makemigrations` & `manage.py migrate` **countless** times, I tried adding instances to which I got a `Operation error: no such table products_store`.

I have the following `models.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

def image_upload_location(instance, filename):
    print instance.name
    print filename
    return "static/images/products/%s" %(filename)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_location)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Variant(models.Model):
    variant_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    variant_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_location, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.variant_name
```

Then on the shell, I tried the following:

```
In [1]: from products.models import Store

In [2]: from products.models import Product

In [3]: Store
Out[3]: products.models.Store

In [4]: Product
Out[4]: products.models.Product

In [5]: Store.objects.all()

OperationalError: no such table: products_store
In [8]: Product.objects.all()
Out[8]: []
```

Seems really strange to me. I also tried deleting all the migrations, and then running all the migrations again, but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the output from the migrations:

```
Migrations for 'products':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Category
    - Create model Product
    - Create model Store
    - Create model Variant
A:try3 a$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, products
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
```

**Update:**
 Output from `manage.py dbshell`

```
SQLite version 3.9.2 2015-11-02 18:31:45
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                   django_migrations          
auth_group_permissions       django_session             
auth_permission              django_site                
auth_user                    products_category          
auth_user_groups             products_product           
auth_user_user_permissions   products_product_categories
django_admin_log             products_variant           
django_content_type
```

Contents of `migrations/0001_initial.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)),
                ('description', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('description', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('main_image', models.ImageField(upload_to=products.models.image_upload_location)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)),
                ('available', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('categories', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, to='products.Category')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Store',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('description', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Variant',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('variant_name', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('description', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('variant_image', models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=products.models.image_upload_location)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)),
                ('available', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('product', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='products.Product')),
                ('store', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='products.Store')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: What is the contents of `sites/migrations/0001_initial.py`? Did you try deleting all the *.pyc files and start over?

Comment: What do you get when you run `python manage.py dbshell` then enter `.tables` ?

Comment: @Selcuk I deleted all the files that were included in the `products/migrations` folder, not sure what you mean by *.pyc

Comment: @ChrisFreeman See updated question

Comment: @McLean25 I mean compiled Python files, ending with the extension pyc. Try deleting the `products/models.pyc` too

Comment: @Selcuk Ah of course. So I deleted all the `.pyc` migrations and the `models.pyc` and then ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` again, still didn't work.

Comment: Could be something to do with SQlite; did you try renaming the database file and generating from scratch?

Comment: @Selcuk Would simply renaming it do anything? Wouldn't I have to delete the db or do you know of a command to completely wipe it?

Comment: You can delete it if you don't have any critical data, but renaming it will also force Django to recreate it.

Comment: @Selcuk Still no luck... I think the solution is going to just be to start over again unfortunately. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the `store` table was dropped from the database and migrations cannot figure out how to add it back. You could always recreate the table in `dbshell`:

```
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                   django_migrations         
auth_group_permissions       django_session            
auth_permission              products_building            
auth_user                    products_category            
auth_user_groups             products_product             
auth_user_user_permissions   products_product_categories  
django_admin_log             products_variant             
django_content_type

sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key s=OFF;
sqlite> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "products_store" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(120) NOT NULL, "description" text NULL);
sqlite> COMMIT;

sqlite> .tables
auth_group                  django_migrations         
auth_group_permissions      django_session            
auth_permission             products_building            
auth_user                   products_category            
auth_user_groups            products_product             
auth_user_user_permissions  products_product_categories  
django_admin_log            products_store               
django_content_type         products_variant
```